# How do I comment on a suggested edit to my topic?

Tags: discussion, comments

This is pretty meta, but I wanted to gently suggest to Sosukodo, regarding his/her comment on my [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18555820/522385) that *StackOverflow is being overrun by title pollution! Tags do not belong in titles! That's why tags are there!*, that EXCESSIVE EXCLAMATION POINTS ARE A BIT LIKE SHOUTING!

The message would have lost none of its meaning if punctuated with simple periods.

Comment: You could @-notify him in the comments, but I would **strongly** advise against that. Generating a comment and notification to talk about the *edit reason*, of all things, is a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: Really?? Suppose I take issue with the edit?

Comment: Well, you can @-notify any editor of your post for that very reason, but there's not really anything to take issue with in this case. Tags are not meant to be in the titles, and *should* be edited out.

Comment: Using too many exclamation points in a description of the reason for the edit is silly, but it does not make the edit invalid. You're making a mountain of a mole hill; the edit was valid (tags don't belong in the title - they belong in the tags).

Comment: I don't take issue with that.  I wanted to suggest that the exclamation points were unnecessary.

Comment: What I do is find old post made by the user and post comment with the advice. If the user reply great, if not I delete the comment anyway after few hours. This way nobody else is affected.

Answer (score 5):

As stated in the comments: anyone who has previously edited the question or answer you're commenting on can be @-notified. It is hardly worth anyone's time though, especially yours.

Comment: An @-notification disputing an edit would be wholly inappropriate, in my opinion: it's irrelevant to the topic.  But what I'm hearing is that there is no way to privately contact the editor to discuss an edit, which is surprising.

Comment: @Chap You'll notice that there is no way to privately contact anybody unless you're a moderator and someone committed an infraction. That's just how we roll. If you want to just tell someone off (however politely) for a bad edit or a poorly worded edit comment, that's likely not a productive use of your time. If you want to raise an issue prompted by an edit (e.g. "should tags be edited out of titles?"), bring it to meta.

Comment: Roll on, then.  I feel that bringing attention to matters of "tone" is not a complete waste of time, and I suspect that there are others, including well-intentioned editors, who would agree.  Thank you for allowing me to raise the subject here.  'Nuff said.